# A method annotated with Before, After, BeforeStep or AfterStep must have one of these signatures:

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, bdd, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

`Trying to create an hooks in cucumber framework getting below error not sure what i am missing
Suppressed:io.cucumber.java.InvalidMethodSignatureException: A method annotated with Before, After, Before Step or After Step must have one of these signatures:

```
 @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep() {
        System.out.println("  @BeforeStep");
    }
@AfterStep
  public void AfterStep(ITestResult scenario) throws IOException { 
     if (ITestResult.FAILURE == scenario.getStatus()) {
         File screenshot =((TakesScreenshot) 
    driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
         FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot,new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse-workspace\\Cucumber_screenshot_Failure\\test-output\\screenshots\\Failure.png"));

    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the relevant parts of the stack trace in the future.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation here:
https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=java#hooks

The correct code for your beforeStep method would look something like this:

```
@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(Scenario scenario){
}
```

The `InvalidMethodSignatureException` tells you that the method signature is incorrect, meaning the return type, parameters, or method scope are invalid for the annotation.

If you add the `Scenario scenario` parameter, it should clear up your issue.

Comment: The first method `beforeStep` is correct. The `Scenario` parameter is optional. Rather the second method `AfterStep` is not correct and causing the error.

Comment: ya know the issue is resolved but screenshot is not attached to failure step
@AfterStep
   public void AfterStep(Scenario  scenario) throws IOException { 
   if (scenario.getStatus() == Status.FAILED) {
    File screenshot =((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot,new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse-workspace\\Cucumber_screenshot_Failure\\test-output\\screenshots\\Failure.png"));

  }}